# How can I ensure the `snd-hda-intel` module is loaded on startup?

Tags: sound, sudo, hda-intel, modprobe

I need to type `sudo modprobe snd-hda-intel` in order to get my sound card to work.

What config file do I need to edit and what edit should I be looking to make so I can get the sound driver loading at start up so I don't have to type this every time?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add `snd-hda-intel` to the end of the file `/etc/modules`. This will make the `snd-hda-intel` module load up automatically at boot time.

You can use: `sudo sh -c 'echo "snd-hda-intel" >> /etc/modules'` to do this.

Comment: It didn't work on my laptop with Debian 9.

Comment: Unless the module is blacklisted.

Comment: Where would I find the Blacklist? @MatthewBrownakaLordMatt

Answer (score 4):

In `/etc/modules` you can put every module (one per line) for those you need to load at boot time.

Running this command will append the module to the file:

```
echo "snd-hda-intel" | sudo tee -a /etc/modules
```

Answer (score 3):

After attempting an "oss4" audio install, I lost audio, and reverting my mistake, did not recover the audio.

Needed to "manually": modprobe snd-hda-intel
every boot....

Until I found that the driver had been put in a blacklist.... on the oss4 attempt.

```
grep snd-hda-intel /etc/modprobe.d/*

/etc/modprobe.d/oss4-base_noALSA.conf:blacklist snd-hda-intel
```

moved the "oss4-base_noALSA.conf" away from the "/etc/modprobe.d"

```
sudo mv /etc/modprobe.d/oss4-base_noALSA.conf /root
```

and now, do not need to manually "modprobe snd-hda-intel" to get audio after every boot....

Hope it helps...

Comment: I found that snd-hda-intel was blacklisted too. I commented out the line and will see if it works on the next reboot.

Comment: @MatthewBrownakaLordMatt i take it you havent rebooted your computer in the last 7 months? lol I commented it out too and am planning to check on next reeboot but heck if i remember to do that like 6 weeks from now

Comment: yep, seems like this works after a reboot