# How to load "snd-hda-intel" at startup

Tags: sound, modprobe, hda-intel

I always have to type in

```
 sudo modprobe snd-hda-intel
```

in order to get my sound card to work
I have already tried the solution to append snd-hda-intel to /etc/modules with

```
 sudo sh -c 'echo "snd-hda-intel" >> /etc/modules'
```

The line is added accordingly into the file, anyways that does not seem to work. Please give advice.

edit:
I did run

```
 dmesg | grep snd
```

--> no result.

afterward i run

```
 sudo modprobe snd-hda-intel
```

and then
I did run

```
 dmesg | grep snd
```

--> see output

output:

```
[  162.098807] snd_hda_intel 0000:01:00.1: Handle VGA-switcheroo audio client
[  162.134560] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0: ALC892: SKU not ready 0x598301f0
[  162.134978] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0: autoconfig for ALC892: line_outs=1 (0x14/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0) type:speaker
[  162.134982] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:    speaker_outs=0 (0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0)
[  162.134985] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:    hp_outs=1 (0x1b/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0)
[  162.134988] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:    mono: mono_out=0x0
[  162.134991] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:    dig-out=0x1e/0x0
[  162.134993] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:    inputs:
[  162.134997] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:      Internal Mic=0x19
[  162.134999] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:      Mic=0x18
[  162.135002] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:      Line=0x1a
```

Comment: Try `dmesg | grep snd` to figure out why it doesn't get autoloaded.

Comment: @mikewhatever - i have edited my answer to add the requested information. What should i do next?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please turn off secure boot using mokutil. Mine had the same problem but got it working by disabling secure boot.

Answer (score 2):

After attempting an "oss4" audio install, I lost audio, and reverting my mistake, did not recover the audio.

Needed to "manually": modprobe snd-hda-intel
every boot....to get audio on Ubuntu

Until I found that the driver had been put in a blacklist.... on the oss4 attempt.

```
grep snd-hda-intel /etc/modprobe.d/*
/etc/modprobe.d/oss4-base_noALSA.conf:blacklist snd-hda-intel
```

moved the "oss4-base_noALSA.conf" away from the "/etc/modprobe.d"

```
sudo mv /etc/modprobe.d/oss4-base_noALSA.conf /root
```

and now, do not need to manually "modprobe snd-hda-intel" after every boot....to get audio on Ubuntu

Hope it helps...

Similar to [How can I ensure the `snd-hda-intel` module is loaded on startup?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/296095/how-can-i-ensure-the-snd-hda-intel-module-is-loaded-on-startup/1118822#1118822)

Comment: yep! this works for me. even just commenting the line from grep in that file made it work (and survive a reboot)

Answer (score 1):

I had issues getting sound to work after upgrading to Ubuntu 20.04.

```
modprobe snd_hda_intel commands failed to load module:snd_hda_intel.
```

The module was missing. I installed it via:

```
uname -r (note kernel version)
apt-get install linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-56-generic
```

This installed the missing module, after this, I could `module:snd_hda_intel` and everything worked!